# jQuery cookie plugin read JSON Object

Tags: javascript, cookies, jquery-plugins

I am saving from PHP some data in assoc array. There are some Id's putted in an array and then json_encoded:

```
$ids = array(id => id, id2 => id2);
json_encode($ids);
store in the cookie ...
```

I am using this plugin for jQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

This is the string, what is stored in the cookie with value: "xxx"

```
%7B%2222504454%22%3A22504454%7D

path: "/"

domain: ".domain.com"
```

When I use this one:

```
var test = $.cookie( 'xxx');
```

I am receiving only `Object` as return.

How to read this array?

Comment: Since you encoded the value with json, you are going to need to decode it/address it differently from a simple value. You must be trying to access it as a string and it tells you 'I am an object'.

Comment: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON and JavaScript don't support "*associative*" `Array`s<sup>1</sup>. Their equivalent is [an `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

```
<?php echo json_encode(array(id => 'foo', id2 => 'bar')); ?>
```

```
{ "id": "foo", "id2": "bar" }
```

Their [`Array`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are sorted collections with indexes from `0` to `length - 1` and can be generated from a non-associative array.

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('foo', 'bar')); ?>
```

```
[ "foo", "bar" ]
```

Note:

1. JavaScript `Array`s can be given non-numeric keys after they've been instantiated, though such keys will not be counted in the `length`.

---

Beyond that distinction: to treat the `cookie` as either an `Object` or `Array`, you'll need to parse it with either [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

```
var test = JSON.parse($.cookie('xxx'));

console.log(test.id);
console.log(test.id2);
```