# php json_encode() is encoding in a way that JavaScript JSON.parse can't decode

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to work between PHP and Javascript, reading and writing the same cookie that contains a json value that I read into an array in both JS and PHP.

If I save the cookie having used json_encode() on my php array I find that the contents of the resulting cookie are all encoded, as if url encoded.

The problem is that when I try to then read that cookie and decode the JSON with

```
var existing_array = readCookie('cookie_name');
JSON.parse(existing_array)
```

I get a javascript error (such as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %)

If I use a browser based cookie reader I can see that the array is easily readable when it is saved via javascript:
["644","636"].

However when the array is created in PHP via the json_encode() function the resulting content ends up as something like:  %5B%22644%22%5D.

If this encoding wasn't happening i'm confident that the JS function could decode it.    Has anyone else experienced this?   I'm using PHP 5.5 on Windows 8 and the latest Chrome Browser.

Comment: Can't you just decode in JS? `decodeURI( readCookie('...') )`

Comment: The contents in the cookie is URL encoded. Decode it first if you want to `JSON.parse` it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @Evilzebra, it was simply adding decodeURIComponent at the start of the JS that resolved it.

```
decodeURIComponent(readCookie('cookie_name'));
```

Comment: Looks like a messy solution. Why use a `readCookie()` function that can't read a cookie properly?

Comment: JSON.parse($.cookie(cookie_name')) seems like a better solution, reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318545/jquery-cookie-plugin-read-json-object

Answer (score 4):

Cookies need to be stuffed in HTTP headers so they get encoded for transmision:

```
setcookie('cookie_name', '["644","636"]');
```

... triggers:

```
Set-Cookie: cookie_name=%5B%22644%22%2C%22636%22%5D
```

... and the browser sends this back:

```
Cookie: cookie_name=%5B%22644%22%2C%22636%22%5D
```

Your `readCookie()` function should take care of decoding data properly but it seems it doesn't. If you want to fix it, you can take some ideas from e.g. the [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js) plug-in:

```
function parseCookieValue(s) {
    if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
        // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape...
        s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
    }

    try {
        // Replace server-side written pluses with spaces.
        // If we can't decode the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
        // If we can't parse the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
        s = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
        return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

Please note the `decodeURIComponent` part.